# Getting Error when I trying to delete event

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, sfdc

I am getting error when I trying to delete events and its following

""We can’t delete future events because a flow, trigger, or validation prevented the series from being updated. Disable the flow, trigger, or validation or delete individual events.""

Can you please help me I also checked the debug but did not find anything.